# How to use Javascript in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, jquery

I want to use JavaScript in my own custom Magento Module.

Unfortunately I do not have any clue how I can access it.

Another important thing to note is that I need to have access to JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just type this following Code (access jQuery with "jQuery"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(["jquery","domReady!"], function (jQuery) {
    //Youre Code
  });
</script>
```

I hope this will help you. Have a good time using Magento 2.3!